# Google Geocode API only USA results

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoder

I'm using the simple URL that Google provides for zip code lookup.

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=90210&sensor=true

This URL will return results for the whole world but how do I limit those to just the USA? I looked it up but can't find anything. I'd hate to code more than necessary to make sure there are not any US addresses when there might be a way to add to the URL and get the:

```
  {
  "results" : [],
  "status" : "ZERO_RESULTS"
  }
```

This is what the API returns if there are no results at all. Much easier.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [component filtering](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=nl#ComponentFiltering) and use the `country` and the `postal_code` components

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=true&components=country:US|postal_code:90210

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps Google had a glitch when you tried the link you provided in your question. I just tried it and it worked fine:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "90210",
               "short_name" : "90210",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Beverly Hills",
               "short_name" : "Beverly Hills",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "short_name" : "Los Angeles County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Beverly Hills, CA 90210, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1354771,
                  "lng" : -118.3867129
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.065094,
                  "lng" : -118.4423781
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 34.1030032,
               "lng" : -118.4104684
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1354771,
                  "lng" : -118.3867129
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 34.065094,
                  "lng" : -118.4423781
               }
            }
         },
         "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I thought I clarified but I guess I missed it. 

That URL does return results. I was putting that up as an example however if you enter a random set of 5 numbers as a zip chances are your going to get the 'ZERO_RESULTS' as above. However, I got it to work using a work around. Could have swore that I posted the find on here already. What I did was get an array full of the states and their abbreviations and search that array when I get results from the Geocode API. If the abbreviation doesn't exist I throw an error else I run the rest of the code. Simple.